# How to set complex model object in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, asp.net-mvc-5

Here is the use case.

2 Model Classes:

```
public Class ModelA {
   public long SomeLong {get; set; }
}

public Class ModelB {
   public string SomeString {get;set; }
   public ModelA modelA {get; set; }
}
```

Now - I have two web pages (.cshtml) - View1 & View2.

In the **first page** - View1, user fills a form, and in the post the server gets the ModelA instance of the user

In the second page - View2, user fills another form, and in the post the server gets the ModelA instance of the user, but this time **I'd like to inject the ModelA instance from the first page** to the ModelB that is sent to the server - persist ModelA object and push it to another object.

Since there is only one model per view, I tried to inject ModelA to View2 with viewbag, but I  don't know how to actually set it ModelB property...tried HiddenFor, tried other things.

ideas?

Comment: You could try with tempdata.

Comment: I'll check that out. but - how (within the .cshtml) I do the set function - how do I actually do the ModelB.ModelA = tempdata[whatever] ?

Comment: in the second page you sent to the server de model A or B?

Comment: In the second page I send ModelB hopfully after I set its Property right ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are displaying the values of the first model in the second page, just use the HTML displayfor, etc... And HTML.HiddenFor the values not displaying. These will keep them in the model.

Else you should try to store the model in tempData["modelA"] = ModelA. And get it back in the post method of with ModelA = tempData["modelA"].

Comment: Thanks, I"m trying it, and can't get it work (not sure I use the code block right here in the form). anyway - I need to send ModelB after I set inside it ModelA so in the post the complex action will be sent to the server..If you can examplify how'll do that that would be great.

Comment: ok now I got it! I need to use TempData in the next action (and don't need to "set" it in the view itself..thanks!